# How do I retrieve my ProductID from GridView?

Tags: c#, html

I'm trying to retrieve my ProductID from a gridview, I tried using this code to retrieve my data but it gives the error:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection. Parameter name: index

this is my code:

```
strProductId = GridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Text;
```

This is how the raw gridview looks like

[image: This is how the raw gridview looks like]

This is an example of how it would look like with data

[image: This is an example of how it would look like with data]

Comment: The error message is self explanatory. Your `DataGrid` doesn't contain either 2 rows or 2 columns.

Comment: A little extra detail for beginners - collections (like the Rows and Cells in your line of code) in C# are zero-based. For example, to get the first row in your code you would use GridView1.Rows[0].

Answer (score 0):

You didn't explain how you are sourcing your data, but take a look at the sample code below, and that should help you get things straightened out.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string connetionString;
        SqlConnection connection;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter;
        SqlCommandBuilder cmdBuilder;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataSet changes;
        string Sql;
        Int32 i; 

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connetionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password";
            connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
            Sql = "select * from Product";
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Sql, connection);
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                connection.Close();
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show (ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
                changes = ds.GetChanges();
                if (changes != null)
                {
                    adapter.Update(changes);
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Changes Done");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also . . .

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb; 
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string connetionString;
        OleDbConnection connection;
        OleDbDataAdapter oledbAdapter;
        OleDbCommandBuilder oledbCmdBuilder;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataSet changes;
        int i;
        string Sql;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connetionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Your mdb filename;";
            connection = new OleDbConnection(connetionString);
            Sql = "select * from tblUsers";
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                oledbAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(Sql, connection);
                oledbAdapter.Fill(ds);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show (ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                oledbCmdBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(oledbAdapter);
                changes = ds.GetChanges();
                if (changes != null)
                {
                    oledbAdapter.Update(ds.Tables[0]);
                }
                ds.AcceptChanges();
                MessageBox.Show("Save changes");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```